django gives me a bad request error 400 when I want to fill a table
when I want to fill in the MRZ table it gives me the bad request error knowing that all the attributes are retrieved from my flutter mobile app except for the ccp_account which gives me nothing when I want to print it I retrieve it from the backend and not from flutter. Here is the code for the Mrz models
class MRZ(models.Model):
    id_mrz = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    FK_compte_ccp = models.OneToOneField(CompteCcp, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    photo_passport = models.ImageField(upload_to='mrz_photos/')
    birthDate = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    documentNumber = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    expiryDate = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)


And here is the code of the views where i have the probleme
def remplir_mrz(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        try:
            # Récupérer le token JWT depuis le corps de la requête
            token = request.headers.get('Authorization').split(' ')[1]
            
            print("Données reçues :", request.POST)

            
            print("Token JWT récupéré :", token)

            # Vérifier si le token n'est pas vide
            if token:
                # Décoder le token JWT pour obtenir l'identifiant de l'utilisateur
                decoded_token = jwt.decode(token, settings.SECRET_KEY, algorithms=['HS256'])
                print("Token JWT decoder :", decoded_token)
                user_id = decoded_token['user_id']
                print("user id :", user_id)

                # Rechercher le compte CCP associé à l'utilisateur
                compte_ccp = get_object_or_404(CompteCcp, FK_compte_app=user_id)                
                # Vérifier si les données contiennent une clé 'photo_passport'
                if 'photo_passport' in request.FILES:
                    # Extraire l'image
                    image_file = request.FILES['photo_passport']

                    # Construire le chemin du dossier de l'utilisateur
                    user_folder = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, str(user_id))

                    # Vérifier si le dossier de l'utilisateur existe, sinon le créer
                    if not os.path.exists(user_folder):
                        os.makedirs(user_folder)

                    # Construire le chemin complet du fichier MRZ avec extension .jpg
                    filename = "MRZ.jpg"  # Nom du fichier avec extension .jpg
                    filepath = os.path.join(user_folder, filename)

                    # Enregistrer l'image dans le dossier de l'utilisateur avec le nom MRZ.jpg
                    with default_storage.open(filepath, 'wb+') as destination:
                        for chunk in image_file.chunks():
                            destination.write(chunk)

                    # Traiter les données MRZ reçues du client
                    document_number = request.POST.get('document_number')
                    birth_datetime_str = request.POST.get('birth_date')
                    expiry_datetime_str = request.POST.get('expiry_date')

                    # Convertir la chaîne de date et d'heure en objet datetime
                    birth_datetime = datetime.strptime(birth_datetime_str, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f")
                    expiry_datetime = datetime.strptime(expiry_datetime_str, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f")

                    # Extraire uniquement la date
                    birth_date = birth_datetime.date()
                    expiry_date = expiry_datetime.date()
                    
                    print("documebt_number",document_number)
                    print("birth_date",birth_date)
                    print("expiry_date",expiry_date)
                    print("file path",filepath)
                    print("compte_ccp",compte_ccp)

                

                    # Enregistrer les données MRZ dans la base de données
                    mrz = MRZ.objects.create(
                        FK_compte_ccp=compte_ccp,
                        photo_passport=filepath,
                        document_number=document_number,
                        birth_date=birth_date,
                        expiry_date=expiry_date
                    )

                    # Afficher un message de succès
                    print("MRZ enregistrée avec succès.")

                    return JsonResponse({'message': 'MRZ enregistrée avec succès'}, status=201)
                else:
                    return JsonResponse({'message': 'Aucune image reçue'}, status=403)
            else:
                return JsonResponse({'message': 'Token JWT manquant'}, status=404)
        except jwt.ExpiredSignatureError:
            return JsonResponse({'message': 'Token JWT expiré'}, status=401)
        except jwt.InvalidTokenError:
            return JsonResponse({'message': 'Token JWT invalide'}, status=401)
        except CompteCcp.DoesNotExist:
            return JsonResponse({'message': 'Aucun compte CCP trouvé pour cet utilisateur'}, status=404)
        except Exception as e:
            return JsonResponse({'message': str(e)}, status=400)
    else:
        return JsonResponse({'message': 'Méthode HTTP non autorisée'}, status=405)

And the result in the server :
Données reçues : <QueryDict: {'document_number': ['308491574'], 'birth_date': ['2001-08-27T00:00:00.000'], 'expiry_date': ['2033-01-08T00:00:00.000']}>
Token JWT récupéré : eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VyX2lkIjoxMCwidXNlcm5hbWUiOiJyaXNlMkBnbWFpbC5jb20iLCJleHAiOjE3MTQ4MjQ2MDMsImVtYWlsIjoicmlzZTJAZ21haWwuY29tIn0.38Afbpt0HNAbkY_PdXZ5sPN1ObtjFoa5JtkLmGfVwhw
Token JWT decoder : {'user_id': 10, 'username': 'rise2@gmail.com', 'exp': 1714824603, 'email': 'rise2@gmail.com'}
user id : 10
documebt_number 308491574
birth_date 2001-08-27
expiry_date 2033-01-08
file path C:\Users\morsi\Documents\python\Poste_Projet\media\10\MRZ.jpg
Bad Request: /compte/api/remplir_mrz/
[04/May/2024 12:11:17] "POST /compte/api/remplir_mrz/ HTTP/1.1" 400 63


for some reason, there is no print for the line:
print("compte_ccp",compte_ccp)
what is the response message you get?

this line gives me nothing

the fields you set in .create does not correspond to your models fields. (except for two of them)

@Niko how do I correct this

Replace the snake_case fields on your object creation by the CamelCase as built in your model.

@Niko same problem
